# How do I locate and disable background PGP and Kapersky start up programs?

Tags: macos, terminal, startup

I had to uninstall Kapersky by deleting the application but the item still shows up on my task bar when I restart.

Also, I have PGP installed on my mac, but when I telnet to port 25 of another server, I get a "PGP Universal Proxy" service that I want to disable.

I don't see any way to disable either of these in the default GUI and assume this is buried in some OSX specific configuration.  Where should I look?

Comment: by default GUI do you mean System Preferences > Users & Groups > Startup Items?

Comment: Kaspersky will have a proper uninstaller, as it needs to sit below the regular application layer to do its job.